# horizontally center, and don't offset other content vertically

Tags: javascript, html, positioning, centering

i have a flash based site.
i would like to position an ad on top of it with javascript (centered horizontally like the site).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pw_d=document;
pw_d.projectwonderful_adbox_id = "00000";
pw_d.projectwonderful_adbox_type = "0";
</script>
```

the flash site is all in 1 flash container.  i plan to just leave a visual gap in the flash site for the ad to hover over.

i don't know the html or javascript required to do this.
still searching, this seems like it might be somewhat common.

i assume i will be using div(s)

the reference site:

http://www.charbythevampirate.com/shell.html?page=comics&comic=24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something quick I mocked up.

http://jsfiddle.net/meNVU/

Basically, you want to position your image absolutely in css, then set both the `top` and `left` properties to 50%. After that, set `margin-left` and `margin-top` to half the width * -1 and half the height * -1 respectively. Then, just set the `z-index` on the `<object>` embedding the flash to 0, and the `z-index` for the image to 1. That should (and did) get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your script in a `div`

```
<div style="width:auto;margin 0 auto;padding-bottom: 10px">
<script type="text/javascript">
var pw_d=document;
pw_d.projectwonderful_adbox_id = "00000";
pw_d.projectwonderful_adbox_type = "0";
</script>
</div>
```

`padding-bottom: 10px;` will leave some space below the add before the rest of your flash, or you can take it out, or increase the number of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

this example by Matt McDonald: https://stackoverflow.com/users/342129/matt-mcdonald

http://jsfiddle.net/meNVU/

***my final code**

shell.css

```
body {background-color: #000000;}

div#ad
{
    width: 728px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-left: -365px;
    margin-top: 77px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;   
}
```

shell.html  (which requires my flash Object to be wrapped in javascript for resizing with flash, for a browser scroll-bar)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Charby The Vampirate</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" href="shell.css" />


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var myQueryString=document.location.search;
if (myQueryString[0]='?')
     {
        myQueryString=myQueryString.substr(1, myQueryString.length-1);
     }
var flashvars = { 
    dat: escape(myQueryString)
};
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1
if(is_chrome == true){
    var params = {
      allowFullScreen: "true", 
      menu: "false", 
      wmode: "transparent" 
    };
}else{
    var params = {
      allowFullScreen: "true", 
      menu: "false", 
      wmode: "window" 
    };

}
var attributes = {
  id: "resized", 
  name: "resized", 
  wmode: "window" 
};

swfobject.embedSWF("shell.swf", "resized", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>



<div id="ad">
    <!-- Beginning of Project Wonderful ad code: -->
    <!-- Ad box ID: 38564 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var pw_d=document;
    pw_d.projectwonderful_adbox_id = "43066";
    pw_d.projectwonderful_adbox_type = "5";
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.projectwonderful.com/ad_display.js"></script>
    <!-- Ending of Project Wonderful ad code: -->
</div>

</head>

<body>
<div id="resized" align="center"></div>
</body>
<script>
function ResizeFlash(newHeight){

    $("#resized").css("height",newHeight);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice to see you got it working. Sorry I wasn't available to see it though.